# How do I not call the method if the 2 user inputs doesn't satisfy the condition in the method?

Tags: java

```
public static int computeProduct(int N1, int N2) {
    int product = N1 * N2;
    if (N1 < 10 || N1 > 50 || N2 < 10 || N2 > 50) {
        System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again.");
        System.out.println("0");
    }
    return product;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Numbers must be in the range of 10 to 50, inclusive");
    System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
    int N1 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
    int N2 = scanner.nextInt();

    int product = computeProduct(N1,N2);
    System.out.println(product);
}
```

When the numbers are within range, the code works as specified, printing the product of the 2 user inputs. But when the condition is not met, the product still get printed along with the 2 statements in the if condition. How do make it so that only the 2 statements get printed and not the product?

Comment: You can move the `if()` check outside the `computeProduct()` method and inside the `main()` method and do the check there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the implementation of computeProduct as follows

```
public static int computeProduct(int N1, int N2) {
        int product = N1 * N2;
        if (N1 < 10 || N1 > 50 || N2 < 10 || N2 > 50) {
            System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again.");
            return 0;
        }
        return product;
    }
```

Sample I/P and O/P

```
Numbers must be in the range of 10 to 50, inclusive
Enter the first number:
1
Enter the second number:
23
Number is not in range, please try again.
0
```

Or the better solution is , you should calculate only if nos are valid

```
public static int computeProduct(int N1, int N2) {
        int product = 0;
        if (N1 < 10 || N1 > 50 || N2 < 10 || N2 > 50) {
            System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again.");
        }
        else {
            product = N1 * N2;
        }
        return product;
    }
```

Sample I/P and O/P

```
Numbers must be in the range of 10 to 50, inclusive
Enter the first number:
1
Enter the second number:
2
Number is not in range, please try again.
0
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for range before calling `computeProduct`. Something like this:

```java
public static int computeProduct(int N1, int N2) {
    return N1 * N2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Numbers must be in the range of 10 to 50, inclusive\nEnter the first number:");
    int N1 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
    int N2 = scanner.nextInt();

    if (N1 < 10 || N1 > 50 || N2 < 10 || N2 > 50)
        System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again.\n0");
    else
        System.out.println(computeProduct(N1,N2));
}
```

Comment: You can also use Math.Max(N1, N2) > 50 || Math.Min(N1, N2) < 10 if you want it too look a bit shorter